# Как организовать множественный выбор данных?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, wtforms

Подскажите, как организовать множественный выбор данных в собственном поле ввода? По типу того, как это сделано по дефолту:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пытаюсь использовать Select2TagsField, но не понимаю, как заполнить его данными, при попытке выбора выводит `No matches found`:

```
class CustomModelView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ('things_list',)
    form_extra_fields = {
        'things_list': Select2TagsField(
            'Things',
            data=['asdfasdf','asfdasdfasfasfd'],
            coerce=int
        ),
    }
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался прикрутить [родственное решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24928528/5587299), но в этом случае не выводит вообще ничего:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Если используете WTForms, то в нём есть FieldList, который в свою очередь может содержать одно и более полей для каждого элемента FieldList.

```
class IPV4(Form):
    ip = TextField('IPv4', validators=[validators.Required()])
    mask = TextField('Маска', default='255.255.254.0', validators=[validators.Required()])

class Network(Form):
    ipv4 = FieldList(FormField(IPV4), min_entries=1)
```

Выборка уже непосредственно при получении данных

```
@app.route('/form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    dataform = Network(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for ipv4 in dataform.ipv4.data:
            data[0]['ipv4'].append({'ip': ipv4['ip'],
                'netmask': ipv4['mask']})
    return render_template('form.html', dataform=dataform)
```

Поля можно добавлять динамически через jQuery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня самый большой косяк именно с добавлением новых полей, так как не умею в яваскрипт. Вообще думал, что сначала добавлю детей, потом при нажатии кнопки "добавить" в новом окне появится x полей "количесво, цена" (или "IPv4, Маска", где х - кол-во детей), в которые уже и внесу данные, можно ли так сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос: Если цель именно в добавлении уже на форме, то причем тут Python в принципе? Изучайте тогда JavaScript, и теги сразу ставьте соответствующие у вопроса, с его переформулировкой. Если вопрос в разрешении, то да, я разрешаю Вам добавлять именно предопределённое количество полей, но тогда Вам придётся убирать пустые в скрипте. У меня просто плюс сделанный так [+] и при нажатии добавляется поле ниже.

Comment: Поясняю: вариант с вариацией числа полей на форме меня устраивает, просто как его организовать? Можете кинуть небольшой пример? Я просто изначально подумывал, что нажатие кнопки "добавить" вызовет скрипт, который откроет новое окно (или изменит форму - как вы предлагаете) с нужным количество полей (в зависимости от количества детей), куда я уже внесу доп. данные. А так получается вы дали ответ с кодом, в написании которого у меня нет особых трудностей, и добавили "Поля можно добавлять динамически через jQuery" - типа "а яваскрипт сам учи", в то время как с ней-то у меня и проблемы. Кроме того.

Comment: Вы вольны дополнять вопросы. Я ищу подходящий инструмент, и яваскрипт лишь один из них - так зачем добавлять его в теги?

Comment: Да, судя по всему, я перепутал ответ на этот вопрос с ответом на этот - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC. :-)))

Comment: Здесь https://github.com/RemiZOffAlex/pytin-agent/tree/master/webpxe есть пример работающего кода с добавлением поля по нажатию. Адаптируйте код под себя. Вопрос дополнять нет необходимости, т.к. он самодостаточен, и ответ соответствует сути вопроса.

Comment: Сути вопроса соответствует лишь фраза "Поля можно добавлять динамически через jQuery", так как вопрос стоял именно о переменном числе детей.