# Добавление детей к родителям в сложной связи Многие-ко-Многим

Tags: javascript, python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Подскажите решение, как наиболее просто организовать добавление детей к родителям, если их связь дополнена характеристикой? Сумбурно, но думаю изображение всё пояснит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы можете видеть, связывающая таблица характеризуется не только ссылками на потомков и родителей, но и атрибутами "цена" и "количество". Алхимия предоставляет два шаблона для связей МкМ, и если с шаблоном [assotiation_table](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) во flask-admin проблем нет - я просто добавляю детей в список:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
то использование шаблона [объект ассоциации](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) (мой случай) добавляет ряд сложностей:

- Изначально неизвестно, сколько потомков будет у родителя
- Как организовать ввод данных из набора полей (в моём случае, полагаю, будет x полей (цена, количество), где x - заранее неизвестное количество потомков)

Я бы предпочёл и вовсе не связываться с ассоциативным объектом, но как в таком случае охарактеризовать связь?
Поясню, что в общем и целом всё работает по дефолту, но для создания связи я должен:

- Создать родителя в представлении "родители"
- Создать потомков в представлении "потомки"
- Создать x связей в представлении "потомок-родитель"

В то время как я ищу способ связать их в момент создания родителя, как если бы я использовал assotiation_table pattern

Answer (score 1):

Ммм у вас есть Вещи и Заказы , Тобишь у одной вещи может быть много заказов и в тоже время у одного заказа может быть много вещей . Значит ваша модель связи это ManyToMany, в таблце ордерлист у вас должен быть ForeignKeyField на заказ и вещь. Как это употреблять , сначала создается заказ где ты указваешь ИД покупателя и статус, потом берете нужные тебе вещи , и создаешь ордерлисты где заказ - вещь , столько сколько вещей. 
Пример кода на ORM PeeWee

```
buyer_id = Buyer.get(name = 'Oleg Ivanovich')# берем из базы покупателя
order_obj = Order.create(bayer_id=buyer_id) # создаем покупателя
things = ['Odejda', 'Zapanki', 'sosiski',] # псевдо список вещей
for thing in things:
     thing_obj = Things.get(name=thing) # достаем из базы саму вещь 
     Orderlist.create(order_id = order_obj, thing_id = thing_obj) #создает запись в таблице
```

После всех манипуляций мы можем увидеть к каким заказам у нас относится вещь , и какие вещи в заказе.

Comment: Тобишь - это что?  Таблица?

Comment: Слово паразит , можно интерпритировать Тобишь-получется.