# Динамическое добавление полей в форму

Tags: html, jquery, python, flask-admin

Пытаюсь ответить на [свой же вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528281/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8-%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC). Задача состоит в том, чтобы охарактеризовать потомков при добавлении их к родителю в сложной связи многое-ко-многим. Flask-admin сгенерировал стандартную форму:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Создаём родителя и добавляем к нему двух потомков. Теперь нужно охарактеризовать связь, введя цену и количество каждого товара в соответствующие поля, чтобы выглядело примерно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
CRUD-генератор с такой задачей не справится, полагаю, что можно добавить нужные поля с помощью jQuery, подскажите, как это можно сделать? Оригинальный код формы:

```
    <form action="" method="POST" role="form" class="admin-form form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="things_list" class="col-md-2 control-label">Things
        &nbsp;
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-10">          
      <select class="form-control" data-role="select2" id="things_list" multiple name="things_list"><option value="10">Конденсатор электролитический 0,22 мкФ</option><option value="9">Конденсатор электролитический 0,47 мкФ</option><option value="11">Конденсатор электролитический 0,55 мкФ</option><option value="15">Корпус А220 ПРО</option><option value="14">Корпус А250 ПРО</option><option value="16">Корпус А350 ПРОМ</option><option value="17">Плата А2 mk1</option><option value="19">Плата А250 ПРО в сборе</option><option value="18">Плата А3 mk3</option><option value="20">Плата А350 ПРОМ в сборе</option><option value="7">Резистор 1 кОм</option><option value="8">Резистор 10 кОм</option><option value="6">Резистор 100 Ом</option><option value="21">САИ Ариа 250 ПРО</option><option value="22">САИ Ариа 350 ПРОМ</option><option value="12">Транзистор IGBT 1200В 140А</option><option value="13">Транзистор IGBT 1200В 180А</option></select>          
    </div>        
  </div>            
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 submit-row">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Сохран" />   
  <input name="_add_another" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Сохранить и добавить новый объект" />
  <input name="_continue_editing" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Сохранить и продолжить редактирование" />           
          <a href="/admin/sasles/" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" >Отмена</a>           
      </div>
    </div>        
    </form>
```

Comment: jQuery: element.append("html"), element.html("html") и т.д.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015335/jquery-html-vs-append,
http://api.jquery.com/append/,
http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: @DimXenon возникла проблема, о которой я и не подумал - стандартный валидаторы от WTForms не работают с новыми полями.

Comment: Они не видят поля в составе DOM документа. Их раньше приходилось "оживлять" через live (http://api.jquery.com/live/) ныне устаревший. Сейчас скажу, что делать.

Comment: Пока что можете вот эту тему посмотреть: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021436/turning-live-into-on-in-jquery

Comment: Для навески слушателей/обработчиков событий используйте .on() (http://api.jquery.com/on/). Валидаторы WTForms видимо так же навешивать придётся через .on().

Comment: Вероятно, эта тема окажется полезной: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898967/how-to-use-wtforms-in-ajax-validation